# Reading a saved image from sdcard using PhoneGap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am saving a canvas image in sdcard.
I am saving it to the folder called Pictures, and trying to display it back on the device.

Now I have to retrieve it back and display it. I tried the following code:

**Javascript**

```js
var ShowSavedImage = function(Imagename){
        alert("in ShowSavedImage ");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, onFail);

    }

function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("Pictures/b64Image_1372901806166.png", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);  
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
       console.log("Read as data URL");
       console.log(evt.target.result);
       document.getElementById("smallImage").style.display='block'; 
       document.getElementById("smallImage").src = evt.target.result;   
    }; 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div data-role="page"  id="SavedImage">
            <div data-role="header" class= "header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" >

            <center>
            <h3 id="savedImageHeader"></h3>
            <!-- <img src="" id="savedImageDisplay"  style="display:none;height:auto; max-height:70%; width:auto; max-width:90%;"/> -->
                 <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
                                </center>   

            </div>

        </div>
```

When I tried this code I am getting following error

```
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909): processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at [object Object].<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/list.js:691:45)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:2549:20
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at Object.captureReturnValue [as success] (file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:847:20)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at Object.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:291:46)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:964:21)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at Function.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:1002:17)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at androidExec (file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:856:21)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at [object Object].readAsDataURL (file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:2528:5)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at readDataUrl (file:///android_asset/www/js/list.js:694:12)
07-04 09:26:11.418: I/Web Console(22909):     at gotFile (file:///android_asset/www/js/list.js:683:5) at file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.5.0.js:971
```

I am new to PhoneGap and I didn't understand what went wrong.

How to solve this?

Comment: Seems that `document.getElementById("smallImage").style.display='block';` is getting called before the DOM elements are loaded. Include your js just before `</body>` tag.

Comment: Hello man your code is working for me. i did not get why you faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue not with phonegap, this is a pure js error, I think that your code is running before dom is built. so you may add any button then write your code onclick of this button and test. I think this will make you understand the issue